# Proguard not working after update to Google Play Services 11.8.0

Tags: android, google-play-services, proguard, android-proguard

After updating Google Play Services to 11.8.0 (from 11.6.2) my builds stop working.

This is what I got:

> Unexpected error while computing stack sizes:
>     Class       = [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzao]
>     Method      = [zzf(Ljava/lang/String;)J]
>     Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Stack size becomes negative after instruction [23] invokestatic #146 in [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzao.zzf(Ljava/lang/String;)J])
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 with Gradle 4.4.1

My app build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.fabric.io/public" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1"
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven.fabric.io/public" }
}

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "io.fabric"
apply plugin: "let"
apply plugin: "realm-android"

android {
    compileSdkVersion project.androidSDKVersion
    buildToolsVersion("$androidBuildToolsVersion")

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode project.versionCode
        versionName project.versionName

        minSdkVersion project.androidMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion project.androidTargetSdkVersion

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        resConfigs "pl"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            crunchPngs false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro", "proguard-fresco.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "tier", "minApi"

    productFlavors {
        minApi21 {
            minSdkVersion project.androidMinDevSdkVersion
            dimension "minApi"
        }

        minApi16 {
            minSdkVersion project.androidMinSdkVersion
            dimension "minApi"
        }

        dev {
            multiDexEnabled true
            dimension "tier"
        }

        prod {
            multiDexEnabled false
            dimension "tier"
        }
    }

    variantFilter { variant ->
        def names = variant.flavors*.name

        if (names.contains("prod") && names.contains("minApi21")) {
            setIgnore(true)
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        appendVersionNameVersionCode(variant, defaultConfig)
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        textReport true
        textOutput "stdout"
        fatal "UnusedResources"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    debugImplementation("com.android.support:multidex:$multidexVersion")

    implementation("com.android.support:support-fragment:$androidSupportVersion")
    implementation("com.android.support:support-annotations:$androidSupportVersion")
    implementation("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$androidSupportVersion")
    implementation("com.android.support:design:$androidSupportVersion")
    implementation("com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$androidSupportVersion")
    implementation("com.android.support:cardview-v7:$androidSupportVersion")
    implementation("com.android.support:customtabs:$androidSupportVersion")
    implementation("com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$constraintLayoutVersion")
    implementation("com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:$installReferrerVersion")

    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$playServicesVersion")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$playServicesVersion")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$playServicesVersion")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$playServicesVersion")

    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$playServicesVersion")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$playServicesVersion")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$playServicesVersion")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$playServicesVersion")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:$playServicesVersion")

    (...) // I had removed other dependencies from the list
}

def appendVersionNameVersionCode(variant, defaultConfig) {
    variant.outputs.all { output ->

        def versionCode = android.defaultConfig.versionCode

        output.versionCodeOverride = versionCode
        outputFileName = "${rootProject.name}-${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}-${versionCode}.apk"
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

Comment: Try to **clean** and **re-build** project.

Comment: post your build.gradle here.

Comment: Heisen-Berg I tried. Didn't help.

@AnandJain I just updated my question, please check.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/47894812

Comment: @noogui I don't think so, because I have a different error message, and their solution didn't work for me. But thanks for trying!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to disable optimization entirely, just optimization on the problem class. I had the same issue and got around it by adding the following to the **proguard-rules.pro** file:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
```

Comment: That was enough for me to compile the project. I wasn't needed to use proguard-android.txt instead of proguard-android-optimize.txt or extra lines in build.gradle like debuggable false & useProguard true

Comment: Just like @PiotrWpl said: there is no need to switch back from optimize Proguard setting, just add keep for the internal GMS classes in the setting.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue. As suggested [in this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893266/build-failing-on-play-services11-8-x-with-pro-guard-parser-error/47894812#47894812) you just need to add these lines in your `build.gradle` file :

```
...
release {
   debuggable false
   useProguard true
   ...
}
...
```

I also had to remove the pro guard optimization by replacing :

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

by

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Comment: I faced the exact same issue. Your solution worked.

I used these configurations:
debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

Comment: This is not needed, although it solves the issue, but your binary won't be optimized by Proguard.