# Execution failed for task processDebugGoogleServices or version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, android-support-library

When updating google library version from 9.6.0 to 11.8.0
it creates so many issue, I am not able to compile the code.

Please see the below module Gradle file dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.1'

//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
```

and below is the project gradle depenmdencies

```
  dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-rc1'
//        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha06'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.0.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All google libraries version should have same version:

Change:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
```

and:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
```

Comment: Man you saved my life, I been fixing it from the last 2 hours :(

Comment: When compiling the app it throws me the issue "ProGuard configuration parser error: C:\Users\ahmars\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.8.0.aar"

Comment: @AhmadArslan it seems like there is a problem with progaurd. Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893266/build-failing-on-play-services11-8-x-with-pro-guard-parser-error/47894812) helps you

Comment: No no its fixed I had to disabled the instant Run and build the librraies. now all working good :)