# Build error when use Google Analytics and odfuscation

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, analytics, proguard

I have this error at android:

Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForDebug'.

> ProGuard configuration parser error: C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.8.0.aar\6c960bd35f12660f\proguard.txt line 3:88 no viable alternative at input ''

This occurs when using `minifyEnabled true` and `shrinkResources true`

I try keeping same files in proguard-rules but it doesn't work

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }

-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-libraryjars /libs/libGoogleAnalytics.jar

-keep class com.google.android.apps.analytics.**{ *; }
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [add configuration to turn on ProGuard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893266/build-failing-on-play-services11-8-x-with-pro-guard-parser-error). Doing so will at least work.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            ...
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            ...
        }
    }
```